# Keyboard shortcuts which includes shift key does not work but shift alone works

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, elementary-project, android-studio

Does anyone know why keyboard shortcuts that include shift like control + shift + j in android studio to select all occurrences of something does not work, but shortcuts  like double tap shift works perfectly.

Did some debugging and found out that when using these shortcuts the shift key is not getting registered but using shift alone works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem but using shortcuts like `<shift>+<alt>+>`. I had the same symptom where only one of the modifier keys was being registered at a time, depending on which one was pressed first.

The root cause for me was that `<shift>+<alt>` was already in use by the operating system for cycling between keyboard layouts, thus not sending the keypress to the application(terminal in my case).

Try checking `System Settings > keyboard` and make sure none of the shortcuts you are trying to use are already in use. Also make sure that `switch layout` isn't set to `ctrl + shift`.